# JSLint in Brackets says Audio is not defined, but doesn't complain about Image

Tags: javascript, dom, eslint, jslint, adobe-brackets

I have this code:

```
var me = {
    PreloadImage: function(src) {
        var e = new Image();
        e.src = src;
    },
    CreateAudio : function(src) {
        var c = new Audio(src);
        c.play();
    }
}
```

I have a problem with `new Audio()`, as `JSLint` in Brackets says that `Audio` has not been defined, but it doesn't say the same for `Image`:

[image]

Sometimes I have to do things like `window.console.log` instead of `console.log` because `console.log` was not defined, but if that's the case, what do I have to add before `Audio` and `Image`?

Comment: Does the code still work? That's just a JSLint warning, not a JavaScript error.

Comment: @JJJ No. I think I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `var c = new Audio(src);` use `var c = document.createElement('audio'); c.src=src; c.play();`

Comment: no, either configure the linter correctly or use something like // eslint-disable-line no-undef

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't look like the best way to address that issue to me. You should either change your `JSLint` options or disable that rule on that specific line.

#### Add it as a global

In both `JSLint` and [`ESLint`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals), you can fix it either adding it as a global:

```
{
    "globals": {
        "Audio": true
    }
}
```

#### Add the browser environment

[`ESLint:`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments):

```
{
   "env": {
       "browser": true
   }
}
```

`JSLint:`

```
{
    "browser": true
}
```

#### JSLint options in Brackets

You can also update them in Brackets' preferences:

```
"jslint.options": {
    "browser": true,

     OR

    "globals": {
        "Audio": true
    }
}
```

#### Disable linting or ignore that rule on that line

You can also disable linting for that line or for that specific rule on that line:

`ESLint`:

```
const c = new Audio(src); // eslint-disable-line
```

Or:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
const c = new Audio(src);
```

`JSLint`:

```
const c = new Audio(src); // jslint ignore:line
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as this is not a JS issue, it's a linting config error

Answer (score -1):

You have to wait for the DOM to be ready. Since your are using jQuery, please encapsulate your code in that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Your code...
});
```

You can also use this syntax:

```
$(function () {
  // Your code...
});
```

*(Bonus tip: use the `switch` instruction in your code. `RoNBeta.js` is a bit scary...)*

Comment: I'm not using jQuery in RoNBeta.js. I added a feature to check for it.

Comment: Maybe so, but my JS file is supposed to be flexible.